# Trying to convert json response to dart code but gives 2 error

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert JSON response to dart but over two error

> A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>?

> The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

The code.

```
class GetImProfileDetails {
  List<Params>? params;
  String? status;
  String? statusDesc;

  GetImProfileDetails({this.params, this.status, this.statusDesc});

  GetImProfileDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['params'] != null) {
      params = <Params>[];
      json['params'].forEach((v) {
        params!.add(new Params.fromJson(v)); // Second Error on V
      });
    }
    status = json['status'] as String;
    statusDesc = json['statusDesc'] as String;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.params != null) {
      data['params'] = this.params!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['statusDesc'] = this.statusDesc;
    return data;
  }
}

class Params {
  String? head;
  String? headCode;
  List<String>? options;

  Params({this.head, this.headCode, this.options});

  Params.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    head = json['head'] as String;
    headCode = json['headCode'] as String;
    options = json['options'].cast<String>(); // First Error
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['head'] = this.head;
    data['headCode'] = this.headCode;
    data['options'] = this.options;
    return data;
  }
}
```

My JSON response

```
{
    "params": [
        {
            "head": "Age",
            "headCode": "AG",
            "options": [
                "AG3~Others~1",
                "AG2~45-55~0",
                "AG1~30-45~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Annual Income",
            "headCode": "AI",
            "options": [
                "AI4~>12lacs~1",
                "AI3~<4lacs~0",
                "AI2~8-12lacs~0",
                "AI1~4-8lacs~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Education",
            "headCode": "EDU",
            "options": [
                "EDU4~Post Graduate~1",
                "EDU3~Graduate~0",
                "EDU2~Class XII~0",
                "EDU1~Class X~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Present Occupation ",
            "headCode": "PO",
            "options": [
                "PO9~Financial Advisor~0",
                "PO8~Employee/owner of corporate client~0",
                "PO7~DoctorA  ~0",
                "PO6~DST~0",
                "PO5~DSA~0",
                "PO4~Competition Agent~0",
                "PO3~Career Agent~0",
                "PO27~Used Car DealerA  ~0",
                "PO26~Unemployed~0",
                "PO25~Transporter~0",
                "PO24~Student~0",
                "PO23~Stock Broker ~0",
                "PO22~Service~0",
                "PO21~Self-Employed~1",
                "PO20~Salaried~0",
                "PO2~Business~0",
                "PO19~RTO agent~0",
                "PO18~Project ConsultantA  ~0",
                "PO17~Part Time~0",
                "PO16~Other financial services~0",
                "PO15~New Car DealerA  ~0",
                "PO14~LI Agent~0",
                "PO13~Housewife~0",
                "PO12~Garage~0",
                "PO11~GI-PVT~0",
                "PO10~GI-PSU~0",
                "PO1~Aggregator~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Health PSU Experience",
            "headCode": "HPSUE",
            "options": [
                "HPSUE5~> 10 Years~1",
                "HPSUE4~5-10years~0",
                "HPSUE3~2-5Years~0",
                "HPSUE2~1-2 Years~0",
                "HPSUE1~0-1year~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Health Pvt Experience",
            "headCode": "HPVTE",
            "options": [
                "HPSUE9~5-10years~1",
                "HPSUE8~2-5Years~0",
                "HPSUE7~1-2 Years~0",
                "HPSUE6~0-1year~0",
                "HPSUE10~> 10 Years~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "LI PSU Experience",
            "headCode": "LPSUE",
            "options": [
                "LPSUE5~> 10 Years~1",
                "LPSUE4~5-10years~0",
                "LPSUE3~2-5Years~0",
                "LPSUE2~1-2 Years~0",
                "LPSUE1~0-1year~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "LI Pvt Experience",
            "headCode": "LPVTE",
            "options": [
                "LPSUE9~5-10years~1",
                "LPSUE8~2-5Years~0",
                "LPSUE7~1-2 Years~0",
                "LPSUE6~0-1year~0",
                "LPSUE10~> 10 Years~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "No. of years in the city",
            "headCode": "NYIC",
            "options": [
                "NYIC3~> 7 Years~1",
                "NYIC2~<3 Years~0",
                "NYIC1~3-7 Years~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "GI Annual Potential",
            "headCode": "GANP",
            "options": [
                "GANP7~>100 lakhs~1",
                "GANP6~<3 lakhs~0",
                "GANP5~50-100 lakhs~0",
                "GANP4~5-10 lakhs~0",
                "GANP3~3-5 lakhs~0",
                "GANP2~25-50 lakhs~0",
                "GANP1~10-25 lakhs~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Health Annual Potential",
            "headCode": "HANP",
            "options": [
                "HANP7~>100 lakhs~1",
                "HANP6~<3 lakhs~0",
                "HANP5~50-100 lakhs~0",
                "HANP4~5-10 lakhs~0",
                "HANP3~3-5 lakhs~0",
                "HANP2~25-50 lakhs~0",
                "HANP1~10-25 lakhs~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Motor Annual Potential",
            "headCode": "MAP",
            "options": [
                "MAP7~>100 lakhs~1",
                "MAP6~<3 lakhs~0",
                "MAP5~50-100 lakhs~0",
                "MAP4~5-10 lakhs~0",
                "MAP3~3-5 lakhs~0",
                "MAP2~25-50 lakhs~0",
                "MAP1~10-25 lakhs~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "Potential Club",
            "headCode": "PC",
            "options": [
                "PC5~Silver~0",
                "PC4~Platinum~0",
                "PC3~Partner~0",
                "PC2~Gold~1",
                "PC1~CEO~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "head": "SME Annual Potential",
            "headCode": "SNP",
            "options": [
                "SNP7~>100 lakhs~1",
                "SNP6~<3 lakhs~0",
                "SNP5~50-100 lakhs~0",
                "SNP4~5-10 lakhs~0",
                "SNP3~3-5 lakhs~0",
                "SNP2~25-50 lakhs~0",
                "SNP1~10-25 lakhs~0",
                "999999~Select~0"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "Success",
    "statusDesc": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following. I have rewritten several places where I think you are doing something that are incorrect or not efficient:

```dart
class GetImProfileDetails {
  List<Params>? params;
  String? status;
  String? statusDesc;

  GetImProfileDetails({this.params, this.status, this.statusDesc});

  GetImProfileDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['params'] != null) {
      params = [
        for (Map<String, dynamic> paramsMap in json['params'])
          Params.fromJson(paramsMap)
      ];
    }
    status = json['status'] as String;
    statusDesc = json['statusDesc'] as String;
  }

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'params': params,
        'status': status,
        'statusDesc': statusDesc,
      };
}

class Params {
  String? head;
  String? headCode;
  List<String>? options;

  Params({this.head, this.headCode, this.options});

  Params.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    head = json['head'] as String;
    headCode = json['headCode'] as String;
    options = (json['options'] as List).cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'head': head,
        'headCode': headCode,
        'options': options,
      };
}
```

A general note about the `toJson()` method is that you should just return something that can be JSON encoded. And Dart will also automatically try call `toJson()` on any object that cannot be directly used in a JSON format. So your `GetImProfileDetails.toJson()` are allowed to return an object that contains a list of `Params` since Dart will then call `Params.toJson()` on each `Params`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the 2nd error if think you have to do:

```
json['params'].forEach((Map<String, dynamic> v) { //rest of code
```

Comment: Already tried but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Class Params with this.

```
class Params {
  String head;
  String headCode;
  List options;

  Params({this.head, this.headCode, this.options});

  Params.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    head = json['head'] as String;
    headCode = json['headCode'] as String;
    options = json['options'] as List; // First Error
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['head'] = this.head;
    data['headCode'] = this.headCode;
    data['options'] = this.options;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first error, you are initializing the string list in a wrong way, change your code from

```
Params.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    head = json['head'] as String;
    headCode = json['headCode'] as String;
    options = json['options'].cast<String>(); // First Error
}
//to:
Params.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    head = json['head'] as String;
    headCode = json['headCode'] as String;
    options = List<String>.from(json['options']);
}
```

For the second error:

```
if (json['params'] != null) {
  params = <Params>[];
  json['params'].forEach((v) {
    params!.add(new Params.fromJson(v)); // Second Error on V
  });
}
//Change it to:
if (json['params'] != null) {
  params = <Params>[];
  for (final param in json['params'] ?? [])
    params!.add(new Params.fromJson(param));
}
```

Comment: Both solutions are not working.

Comment: What does it return? an error or does not fetch the data?